# Why do my Jenkins builds still show as success when I've set fail parameters in the performance plugin?

Tags: api, plugins, jenkins, jmeter

I've set up Jenkins to run my jmeter api test plan. I installed the performance plugin and set the error thresholds on a single build to be: unstable > 2% and failure > 5%. However when I run my tests and they have failures greater then 5% the build still shows as a blue circle indicating success. Am I missing a step?

```
summary =     41 in   1.5s =   28.0/s Avg:    16 Min:     0 Max:   251 Err:    17 (41.46%)
Tidying up ...    @ Fri Mar 04 09:28:29 PST 2016 (1457112509659)
... end of run
<br>Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 2% sets the build as unstable
Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 5% sets the build as failure
<BR>Performance: Recording JMeter reports '**/*.jtl'
Performance: Parsing JMeter report file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\LOS API Regression Tests\builds\53\performance-reports\JMeter\log.jtl'.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22011) the cause for this issue. Try to downgrade to a previous version of Performance Plugin. I also spent a lot of time trying to investigate the root cause.

I suggest to use version 1.11 as 1.12 also has some critical issues (critical for my goals at least).